# Sphere packing in a sphere

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I don't know how to prove that maximum radius of inner spheres equals $2\sqrt{3}-3$. I can't imagine it. Could you help me by any tips?

Result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing_in_a_sphere

Comment: There is a drawing in that table that that link takes you to. That should help you imagine how the spheres lie. Or do you want help proving the result $2\sqrt3-3$? Still, that diagram should be a large help. Can you do it in [two dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle)? Because if you can't, then that's a much better place to start. And if you can, then the the dimensional case is basically the same techniques, only more of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's the same, though parameters, indicated in the tables, are different: Maximum radius of inner spheres r, 1-st Table, Enclosing circle diameter R, 2-nd Table.

r=(2√3-3)R

If r=1, then

R=r/(2√3-3)=1/(2√3-3)=(2√3+3)/(12-9)=1+2/√3

Sorry for non-decent format, I'm a rookie in that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I had a problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake. Let's set the plane consisting 3 centers of inner circles. This plane consists the center of large circle (easy proof by central axis symmetry). Then, you have equilateral triangle, each side of which is $2r$, its center coincides with center of large sphere, $R=1$.

Hence, you have an equation for the segment between the triangle's vertex and its center:
$$1-r=\frac{2r}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$r=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2+\sqrt{3}}=2\sqrt{3}-3$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. If finding the answer was such a piece of cake for you, perhaps you have some time left to spare to format it properly :-) [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: It sounds like there is no difference between three spheres in a sphere and three circle in a circle but there is a difference in answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle
(I know that in first link radius is showed and diameter here but if you devide this diameter by 2 it won't be result from first link)